# Not able to add same Users message in Same group of Android Nougat Push Notifications as whatsapp

Tags: android, push-notification

Here I'm trying to show chat messages in groups like whatsapp does in Android 7.0 or more but they're not getting displayed like that. I'm sending local push notifications by getting chat messages from `Node.js`. In android, I'm using socket client to fetch them and sending push notifications to the other user if their apps are in background. Multiple messages are going in one group but when I try to create a new group when some one else send messages its adding in a same group.

[image: Below is the screenshot]

It just updates the title of push notification as I'm doing here:

```
 public static void bundledNotification(String message, String name, String uId) {
    Context context = ApplicationClass.context();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    ++numberOfBundled;
    issuedMessages.add(message);

    //Build and issue the group summary. Use inbox style so that all messages are displayed
    NotificationCompat.Builder summaryBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setGroup(uId);

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Messages:");
    for (CharSequence cs : issuedMessages) {
        inboxStyle.addLine(cs);
    }
    summaryBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_BUNDLED_BASE_ID, summaryBuilder.build());

    //Pending Intent
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, ChatMessageActivity.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra("uid", Integer.parseInt(uId));
    notificationIntent.putExtra(context.getString(R.string.notify_id), Integer.parseInt(uId));
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
    // Adds the back stack
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatMessageActivity.class);
    // Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    //issue the Bundled notification. Since there is a summary notification, this will only display
    //on systems with Nougat or later
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(name))
            .setGroup(uId);

    //Each notification needs a unique request code, so that each pending intent is unique. It does not matter
    //in this simple case, but is important if we need to take action on a specific notification, such as
    //deleting a message
    int requestCode = NOTIFICATION_BUNDLED_BASE_ID + numberOfBundled;
    if (messagesMap.get(uId) != null) {
        messagesMap.get(uId).add(message);
    } else {
        ArrayList<String> messageList = new ArrayList<String>();
        messageList.add(message);
        messagesMap.put(uId, messageList);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_BUNDLED_BASE_ID + numberOfBundled, builder.build());
    }

    AppPreferences.setChatNotificationNumber(context, AppUtils.PUSH_CHATS_NOTIFICATION_NUMBER, requestCode);
    NotificationCompat.Builder childBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentIntent(contentIntent)
            .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle()
                    .bigText(message))
            .setGroup(uId);

    notificationManager.notify(requestCode,
            childBuilder.build());

}
```

From above code it's always creating a one more notification at first time and second time it starts adding messages into old notification. But when I'm trying to add old messages into the thread of same user it creates a new message under main group of notification. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**Use same setGroup and notification(NOTIFICATION_BUNDLED_BASE_ID) id(group wise)**

```
Context context = ApplicationClass.context();
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
    ++numberOfBundled;
    issuedMessages.add(message);

    //Build and issue the group summary. Use inbox style so that all messages are displayed
    NotificationCompat.Builder summaryBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(name)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setGroupSummary(true)
            .setGroup(1001);

    NotificationCompat.InboxStyle inboxStyle =
            new NotificationCompat.InboxStyle();
    inboxStyle.setBigContentTitle("Messages:");
    for (CharSequence cs : issuedMessages) {
        inboxStyle.addLine(cs);
    }
    summaryBuilder.setStyle(inboxStyle);

    notificationManager.notify(1001, summaryBuilder.build());
```

Comment: Its working for base notification. Now I'm adding new notification for the child part. Please check attached screenshot.